# New to Ubuntu - Windows Expert seeking advice

Tags: mono

I'm a .NET developer (how I earn a living).
I would like to learn Ubuntu.
I've installed Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 on my MacAir inside a Parallels VM and it runs perfectly. I'm Pumped!

Now, I'd like to find some documentation specifically for Newbs.
I did a Book Search for "Ubuntu" on Amazon and didn't find much.
Does anyone have any advice for me, or links to documentation specifically targeted to newbs?

Comment: Hi Rob, I'd advise on also joining the Ubuntu Forums if you haven't already done so. http://ubuntuforums.org/  Also there are a few free publications for Ubuntu users. The Ubuntu Manual - http://ubuntu-manual.org/ - Little Orange Ubuntu Book - https://leanpub.com/littleorangeubuntubook - Ubuntu: A Beginners Guide - http://www.makeuseof.com/pages/ubuntu-an-absolute-beginners-guide & of course The Official Ubuntu Book - http://www.amazon.com/The-Official-Ubuntu-Book-Edition/dp/0133017605

Comment: Naa @MadMike all he needs is our very nice open source manual already updated for 13.10 :D :D  (and no I have no relation with it)

Comment: @scouser73 mind making that an answer or can I copy/paste the extra links into mine? :)

Answer (score 6):

I would start here:

**[Ubuntu manual](http://ubuntu-manual.org/)**

> Getting Started with Ubuntu 13.10 is a comprehensive beginners guide for the Ubuntu operating system. It is written under an open source license and is free for you to download, read, modify and share.
>
> The manual will help you become familiar with everyday tasks such as surfing the web, listening to music and scanning documents. With an emphasis on easy to follow instructions, it is suitable for all levels of experience.

Answer (score 3):

I'd advise on also joining the Ubuntu Forums if you haven't already done so. [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/)

Also there are a few free publications for Ubuntu users.

- [The Ubuntu Manual](http://ubuntu-manual.org)
- [Little Orange Ubuntu Book](http://leanpub.com/littleorangeubuntubook)
- [Ubuntu: An Absolute Beginners Guide](http://makeuseof.com/pages/ubuntu-an-absolute-beginners-guide)
- [The Official Ubuntu Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0133017605)

Also there are a couple of great Ubuntu blogs which I'd recommend you bookmark.

[Web Upd8](http://www.webupd8.org/)

[OMG! Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/)

Then there is the [Easy Linux Tips Project](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/) which aims to give the user some very sound advice, such as installing Java, installing multimedia codecs as well as other various topics which may come in useful.